# Как исправить кучу рендеров React

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, функции

Я пытаюсь самостоятельно сделать всплывающие окна в ReactJS у меня есть состояние с массивом объектов, объект в этом массиве и есть уведомление. Этот массив я передаю в компонент обертку и оттуда рендерю каждый Alert,

Сам state:

```
const [notification, setNotification] = React.useState([
    {
      notificationText: 'Hello world!',
      severity: 'success',
      title: 'Not error!',
    },
    {
      notificationText: 'Bye world!',
      severity: 'success',
      title: 'Not succes!',
    },
  ]);
```

Alert обертка

```
  <Stack sx={{ width: '100%' }} spacing={2}>
      {notification.map((item, i) => (
        <AlertItem
          key={item.notificationText + i}
          item={item}
          {...item}
          closeNotification={closeNotification}
        />
      ))}
  </Stack>
```

Функция удаления элемента из массива

```
  const closeNotification = (item) => {
    let filteredNots = notification.filter((el) => el !== item);
    setNotification(filteredNots);
  };
```

***Сам компонент тут то и возникает проблема ререндеров***

```
const AlertItem = ({ item, notificationText, severity, title, closeNotification }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      closeNotification(item);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Alert onClose={() => closeNotification(item)} severity={severity}>
      <AlertTitle>{title}</AlertTitle>
      {notificationText}
    </Alert>
  );
};
```

***проблема*** - когда в массиве например 4 элемента количество ререндеров с каждым разом растет на 2 (сначала 4 потом 6 потом 8 и т.д), с чем это связано??

Как это исправить? Буду ОЧЕНЬ благодарен ответу!

Comment: `setNotification(filteredNots);` - тут ошибка. setNotification асинхронный, поэтому надо писать так: `setNotification(p => p.filter((el) => el !== item))`

Comment: @entithat, это не решает мою проблему, так же происходят много ненужных рендеров, я вывожу в консоль notification и после каждого удаления увеличивается количество вывода в коносоль notification.

Comment: @entithat, так же если вручную удалить alert, то после вызова setTimeout closenotification, он снова появится, может вы знаете с чем это связано? Буду очень благодарен ответу

Comment: было бы хорошо сделать пример на codesandbox

Comment: @entithat, https://codesandbox.io/s/young-snowflake-4c0oo

Comment: запустил, поменял то, что писал выше и не вижу никакой проблемы, работает как надо

Comment: @entithat, Действительно работает, я так понял правильно возвращать старый state и изменять его. Спасибо вам большое

Comment: Да, функция setNotification принимает колбек с одним параметром - все notification, поэтому надо работать с ними, а не с notification переменной.